# NimGame issue please assist

Tags: java

I am having an issue with my Nim Game running infinitely on the third option of my method. The code runs the game and presents the winner but it runs infinitely. The third method is used in this code to run the game many different times and record how many times each computer has won.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NimGame
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int computerMove = 0;
            int computer2Move = 0;
        int userMove = 0;
        int elementsRemaining = 0;
        int take = 0;
        int mode;
        int times;
        int initial = 0;
        int comp1wins = 0;
        int comp2wins = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Which mode would you like to run the game?");
        System.out.println("1) Player Mode ");
        System.out.println("2) AI vs AI Single Mode");
        System.out.println("3) AI vs AI building mode");
        mode = sc.nextInt();

        if(mode==1)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter number of elements to start.");
            elementsRemaining = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How many elements can you take at a time?");
            take = sc.nextInt();

            while(elementsRemaining > 0)
            {
                computerMove = getComputerMove(elementsRemaining, take);
                System.out.println("Computer takes "+computerMove);
                elementsRemaining -= computerMove;

                System.out.println("Now there are "+elementsRemaining+" elements remaning.");
                System.out.println();

                if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println("How many elements do you want to remove? (1 to " + take + ")");
                userMove = sc.nextInt();

                while((userMove <1) || (userMove > take))
                {
                    System.out.println("Taking " + userMove + " elements is not allowed, please choose from 1 to " + take + ".");
                    System.out.println();
                    userMove = sc.nextInt();
                }

                elementsRemaining -= userMove;

                System.out.println("Now there are " + elementsRemaining + " elements remaining.");
                System.out.println();


                if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(mode==2)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter number of elements to start.");
            elementsRemaining = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How many elements can you take at a time?");
            take = sc.nextInt();

            while(elementsRemaining > 0)
            {
                computerMove = getComputerMove(elementsRemaining, take);
                System.out.println("Computer takes "+computerMove);
                elementsRemaining -= computerMove;

                System.out.println("Now there are "+elementsRemaining+" elements remaning.");
                System.out.println();

                if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer 1 wins!");
                    return;
                }

                computer2Move = getComputer2Move(elementsRemaining, take);
                System.out.println("Computer takes "+computerMove);
                elementsRemaining -= computerMove;

                System.out.println("Now there are "+elementsRemaining+" elements remaning.");
                System.out.println();

                if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer 2 wins!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(mode==3)
        {

            System.out.println("How many times would you like to run the game?");
            times = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter number of elements to start.");
            initial = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How many elements can you take at a time?");
            take = sc.nextInt();

            elementsRemaining = initial;

            for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
            {
                while(elementsRemaining > 0)
                {
                    computerMove = getComputerMove(elementsRemaining, take);
                    System.out.println("Computer takes "+computerMove);
                    elementsRemaining -= computerMove;

                    System.out.println("Now there are "+elementsRemaining+" elements remaning.");
                    System.out.println();

                    if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer 1 wins!");
                        comp1wins++;
                        elementsRemaining = initial;

                    }

                    computer2Move = getComputer2Move(elementsRemaining, take);
                    System.out.println("Computer takes "+computer2Move);
                    elementsRemaining -= computer2Move;

                    System.out.println("Now there are "+elementsRemaining+" elements remaning.");
                    System.out.println();

                    if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer 2 wins!");
                        comp2wins++;
                        elementsRemaining = initial;

                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Computer 1 wins: " + comp1wins);
            System.out.println("Computer 2 wins: " + comp2wins);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }





    public static int getComputerMove(int left, int take)
    {
        if(left == 1)
        {
           return left;
        }
        else
        {
           return (int)(Math.random()*take)+1;
        }
    }

    public static int getComputer2Move(int left, int take)
    {
        if(left == 1)
        {
           return left;
        }
        else
        {
           return (int)(Math.random()*take)+1;
        }
    }
}
```

If I had to make a guess on the issue, I would have to say there is a problem with the nested while loop in my for loop. Any help or suggested changes to make would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ou are right. In case of `elementsRemaining` is lower the zero you set it to the `initial` value. So it is every time grater then zero at the beginning of the `while` loop. You should take a boolean variable to decides, if your run the `while` loop again or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the last one else you write twice

```
 if(elementsRemaining <= 0) 
 {
    ....
    elementsRemaining = initial;
 }
```

but the elementsRemaining <=0 is exactly the condition that is needed to exit the internal loop!